# How to create an email shot in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email

Guys I need to create a type of e-mail trigger, that I don't think is in magento 2. I need the user to click on a button, so that it should send an e-mail to the user. I don't know where to start, does anyone know any content that I can read about, about how to create a module to send e-mail? I tried to find it and I couldn't, if anyone knows of any content or something that I can read, it will help me a lot.

Comment: In order get started with custom Email template and send it from custom module, please refer to this https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/send-mail-from-custom-module-magento-2/

Comment: I tried to follow but it doesn't seem to have worked: /